# Extract Block Around Index from ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

I have a 5D array with shape `(80, 180, 144, 160, 11)` (80 3D-images of size 180*144*160 each with 11 channels) and a set of indices referring to this array with shape `(n, 4)` (that is `n` indices referring to which image and which 3D-pixel I am interested in).

Now to the question, I want to extract "blocks" with shape `(18, 18, 20)` centered around every index and preserving all channels. This will yield an ndarray of shape `(n, 18, 18, 20, 11)`. Also, if an index is too close to the border of the 3D-image as to not fit the entire block then I want to 0-pad the image.

I have managed to do this myself with a for-loop over every index but the performance is rather poor unfortunately (~10 s for `n`=100). I need to do this for `n`s in the range of 10 000 - 1 000 000 so my solution is not really an option.

My attempt where the images are given in `images` and the indices in `block_indices`:

```
block_shape = (18, 18, 20)
blocks = np.empty((0,) + block_shape + (11,))
for index in block_indices:
    block = np.pad(images[index[0]], ((block_shape[0], block_shape[0]),
                                       (block_shape[1], block_shape[1]),
                                       (block_shape[2], block_shape[2]),
                                       (0, 0)))[index[1]+int(block_shape[0]/2):index[1]+int(3*block_shape[0]/2),
                                                index[2]+int(block_shape[1]/2):index[2]+int(3*block_shape[1]/2),
                                                index[3]+int(block_shape[2]/2):index[3]+int(3*block_shape[2]/2),
                                                ...]
    blocks = np.append(blocks, block[np.newaxis, ...], axis=0)
```

I was thinking that this can probably be done really quickly with slicing and fancy array indexing but I have tried to no avail. Do you have any suggestions how this can be done more quickly? Thanks in advance!

PS: The numbers presented can vary a bit but should give you a rough idea of the scale.

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone looking to do the same thing in the future**

I have managed to come up with another solution which is a lot faster and scales better. It involves use of a "shifting" block matrix, `np.tile`, flattening and some reshaping. One caveat is that the indices of the blocks need to be given in a 1D array of length `n` where each index corresponds to the index in a flattened array of 3D-images. One can quite easily convert between these different representations however.

For brevity I will only explain the main concepts of the method and then post a working code example, here goes.

**Main concepts:**

1. First we flatten or `images` array so that it gets shape `(80*180*144*160,11)`.
2. Now we need to come to the realisation that the blocks we are after can be accessed from the flattened array according to a predictable pattern which is only shifted along depending on the location of the block.
3. These elements can be taken out with `np.take` so long as we know the indices.
4. Lastly the result of `np.take` can be reshapened into an array of blocks.

**Working code example:**

```
# Make a 3D-image which enumerates all pixels.
image_pixel_enumeration = np.arange(180*144*160).reshape(180, 144, 160)

# Get the index pattern of a block.
block_shifts = image_pixel_enumeration[:block_shape[0], :block_shape[1], :block_shape[2]].flatten() \
               - image_pixel_enumeration[int(block_shape[0]/2), int(block_shape[1]/2), int(block_shape[2]/2)]

# Tile an array with the pattern, one for each block.
block_shifts = np.tile(block_shifts, (len(block_indices), 1))

# Tile an array with the block center indices add to them the pattern.
validation_data_indices = np.tile(block_indices, (np.prod(block_shape), 1)).transpose() + block_shifts

# Take out elements.
validation_data = np.take(x_test.reshape((-1, 11)), validation_data_indices.flatten(), 0, mode='clip')

# Reshape into blocks.
validation_data = validation_data.reshape((-1,) + block_shape + (11,))
```

This method takes (on my machine) approximately 0.1 s, 0.2 s and 1.4 s for 10, 100 and 1 000 indices respectively whilst the old method took approximately 1 s, 16 s and 900 s for the same number of indices. A massive improvement!

PS. Note that this solution does not solve the issue of blocks extending beyond the original image and can potentially pick pixels from the wrong images or wrong slices in these cases.